# How can I build libQt5Declarative.so?

Tags: qt, build, qt5, packaging, qtdeclarative

When building `qtdeclarative`, I get the following artifacts:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 4.0K Mar  8 21:17 cmake/
-rw-r--r-- 1 2.1M Mar  8 21:19 libQt5QmlDevTools.a
-rw-r--r-- 1  706 Mar  8 21:19 libQt5QmlDevTools.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.1K Mar  8 21:19 libQt5QmlDevTools.prl
-rw-r--r-- 1  761 Mar  8 21:07 libQt5Qml.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.1K Mar  8 21:07 libQt5Qml.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 Mar  8 21:12 libQt5Qml.so -> libQt5Qml.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 Mar  8 21:12 libQt5Qml.so.5 -> libQt5Qml.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 Mar  8 21:12 libQt5Qml.so.5.6 -> libQt5Qml.so.5.6.3*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 5.1M Mar  8 21:12 libQt5Qml.so.5.6.3*
-rw-r--r-- 1  924 Mar  8 21:12 libQt5Quick.la
-rw-r--r-- 1  998 Mar  8 21:16 libQt5QuickParticles.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.3K Mar  8 21:16 libQt5QuickParticles.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1   29 Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickParticles.so -> libQt5QuickParticles.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   29 Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickParticles.so.5 -> libQt5QuickParticles.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   29 Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickParticles.so.5.6 -> libQt5QuickParticles.so.5.6.3*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 752K Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickParticles.so.5.6.3*
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.3K Mar  8 21:12 libQt5Quick.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 Mar  8 21:16 libQt5Quick.so -> libQt5Quick.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 Mar  8 21:16 libQt5Quick.so.5 -> libQt5Quick.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 Mar  8 21:16 libQt5Quick.so.5.6 -> libQt5Quick.so.5.6.3*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 5.2M Mar  8 21:16 libQt5Quick.so.5.6.3*
-rw-r--r-- 1  887 Mar  8 21:16 libQt5QuickTest.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.3K Mar  8 21:16 libQt5QuickTest.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1   24 Mar  8 21:16 libQt5QuickTest.so -> libQt5QuickTest.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   24 Mar  8 21:16 libQt5QuickTest.so.5 -> libQt5QuickTest.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   24 Mar  8 21:16 libQt5QuickTest.so.5.6 -> libQt5QuickTest.so.5.6.3*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 167K Mar  8 21:16 libQt5QuickTest.so.5.6.3*
-rw-r--r-- 1  997 Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickWidgets.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.3K Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickWidgets.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1   27 Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickWidgets.so -> libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   27 Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5 -> libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5.6.3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   27 Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5.6 -> libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5.6.3*
-rwxr-xr-x 1  97K Mar  8 21:17 libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5.6.3*
drwxr-xr-x 2 4.0K Mar  8 21:17 pkgconfig/
```

I am however looking for `libQt5Declarative.so`. Is there a build flag I can set somewhere to build this artifact?

It seems there are RPMs out there that contain this file so surely there must be a way to build it: https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libQt5Declarative.so.5

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html#qtdeclarative-module-in-qt-5), Qt Declarative has been renamed to Qt Quick 1, since Qt 5. So, you have to link with libQtQuick.so, instead.

But, it has been removed in Qt 5.6. You should port your app.

Comment: I'm building version 5.6.3 and there are definitely libQt5Declarative.so.5.6.3 out there in the wild.

Comment: Unfortunately cannot port app as it ships as a binary (it's the teradici PCoIP client)

Comment: Finally, trying to use libQt5Quick.so.5.6.3 in lieu of libQt5Declarative.so.5.6.3 results in missing symbol errors: symbol _ZTI16QDeclarativeView version Qt_5 not defined in file libQt5Declarative.so.5 with link time reference

Comment: QDeclarativeView has been removed in Qt5.6. You have to use an older version.

Comment: `objdump -T libQt5Declarative.so.5.6.3  | grep QDeclarativeView | wc -l` ⇒ 37